# How to properly setup AngularJS files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Im familiar with the standard way of setting up a `angularjs` project, what I'm trying to do is set the app with separate files for different controllers and directives based on the page. See below for better explanation.

```
www /
   app.js
   index.html
    login /
         loginDirective.js
         loginPage.html
```

This is my apps.js file

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'

(function () {
   'use strict';
    angular.module('app', ['ionic']);

})();


var app=angular.module('app');

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

this is my loginDirective.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app=angular.module('app');

app.config(function($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider

.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    template: '<loginDirective></loginDirective>'
})
})
    app.directive('loginDirective', loginDirective);

function loginDirective() {
    var directive = {
        restrict : 'EA',
        templateUrl : 'loginPage.html',
        controller : loginController,
        controllerAs : 'lg',
        bindToController : true
};

return directive;

}

function loginController() {
var lg = this;
lg.test = 'this is a test';

console.log('RETURN = %s', 'test');

}

})();
```

this is my index.html

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="login/loginDirective.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
<div>
    <div>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
        <ion-nav-title>Sample APP</ion-nav-title>
<ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view>
</div>s
</div>
  </body></html>
```

last but not least loginPage.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div login-directive></div>
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view" class="scroll-bg" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="padding">
  <div  align="center" class="imagecontent">
   <div style="text-align: center">
  <img ng-src="img/logos@2x.png" width="250px">
  </div>
  </div>
      <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" style="color: #ffffff" ng-model="data.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" style="color: #ffffff" ng-model="data.password">
          </label>
      </div >
      <div class="" >
      <div  class="">
      <button class=" button  button-block button-dark" ng-click="login(data)">LOG IN</button>
      </div>
      </div>

  </ion-content>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10%; width: 100%">
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <img ng-src="img/FNC_Logo.png" width="150px">
        </div>
        </div>
  <ion-footer-bar align-title="right" class="footer-bg">
        <div class="col text-right" ng-click="doSomething()">
    <button class="button footerbtn-bg" ></button>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing incorrectly that causes my loginPage.html to not show up?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, because I a novice with AngularJS, but if I were you, I firstly would try to change:

```
templateUrl : 'loginPage.html'
```

into:

```
templateUrl : 'login/loginPage.html'
```

I came to such conclusion, because you included loginPage.js file in index.html, so it tries look loginPage.html in www directory, or in directory where it was called. 
I met such case like yours today, but with images.

Comment: Since they are in the same folder no need for the login. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You state definition has problems:

```
$stateProvider

.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    //This should be kebab-case
    template: '<login-directive></login-directive>'
    //NOT camelCase
    //template: '<loginDirective></loginDirective>'
})
})
```

But I am not sure why you are using a directive for that state when you could define the state with a controller:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl : 'loginPage.html',
    controller : loginController,
    controllerAs : 'lg'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `<div login-directive></div>` into the ion-view.

Also inspect the console to see if `console.log('RETURN = %s', 'test');` is actually outputted. At least you'd then know if the state is active or not.

Like @georgeawg said, you're overcomplicating this by using a directive as template. Why you did that in this example is beyond me. Also, your $state config should be in your app.js file.